# Какую библиотеку использовать для подключения к БД

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, mysqlconnector

Всем добрый день! Второй день мучаюсь пытаясь разобраться с **MySQL Connector / C ++ 8.0**. Для начала были проблемы с компиляцией вроде как все установил что нужно для этой библиотеки.

Потом проблема с выборкой данных метод **res->getString("name")** не работает с полями типа **varchar**. Пришлось написать костыль код которого ниже. После ряда тестов обнаружил что и полями типа **Text** метод тоже выдает исключение непонятное. Так и не понял как мне работать с результатом выборки и получать данные типа текст.

Долго ковырялся в документации но толком ничего не понял. Помогите разобраться с проблемой.

**Как мне получать данные из результата если метод вызывает исключение неизвестное? Возможно кто то пользуется библиотекой и там есть другие методы?**

**Или может быть есть другие библиотеки для подключения к базе данных MySql на C++?**

```
 res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id, name FROM users");
       while (res->next()) {


           std::istream* Name = res->getBlob("name");
           if (Name)
           {
               char pws[50];
               Name->getline(pws, 50);

               string name(pws);


               cout << res->getInt("id") << name << endl;

           }

        }
```

Comment: "не работает" - не описание проблемы

Comment: @user7860670 К сожалению более точно описать проблему сложно. Так как я не понимаю ее сущности... Вот ссылка на мой вчерашний вопрос где я более детально изложил проблему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120423/mysql-connector-c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0 Данный вопрос посвящен больше познавательной части и поиску либо решения существующей проблемы либо поиску альтернативы.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4823279/5045688) пишут: какая collation для колонки задана?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хмммм действительно вариант result->getString( COLUMN_NAME ).c_str() - работает. А есть в документации описание подобного подхода ?? Я не нашел...

Comment: Я думаю, тут специалист именно по мускулю нужен, с коллейшенами разобраться.

Comment: С какими настройками были создана база данных, таблица и колонка?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Настройками чего именно ?? InnoDB, utf8_general_ci ты об этом ??

Comment: `create database`, `create table`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov По этой ссылке можно скачать стандартную базу которую дает MySql для теста https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world.sql.zip Ее я использовал изначально. Сейчас благодаря тебе проблема с выборкой данных решилась. Я сменил базу на другую. Теперь у меня есть проблема с кирилицей )) Я создал новую тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120972/mysql-connector-c-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83