# MySQL, Connector / C ++ Как установить кодировку

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, mysqlconnector

Всем добрый вечер! Снова вопрос по коннектору. База данных в кодировке utf8_general_ci таблицы в кодировке utf8_general_ci программа использует набор символов юникод. Но в таблицах хранятся данные латинскими буквами. При отработке программы в консоль сыпятся кракозябры.

В пхп это решается тремя строчками кода. например

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

**А как задать нужную кодировку используя MySQL, Connector / C ++ ?**

Вот код программы:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mysql/jdbc.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    try {
        sql::Driver* driver;
        sql::Connection* con;
        sql::Statement* stmt;
        sql::ResultSet* res;

        // Create a connection 
        driver = get_driver_instance();



        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
        // Connect to the MySQL test database /

        con->setSchema("crm");

        stmt = con->createStatement();



       res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT id, name, company FROM users");
       while (res->next()) {


               cout << res->getInt("id") << " " << res->getString("name").c_str() << " " << res->getString("company").c_str() << endl;



        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    }
    catch (sql::SQLException& e) {

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: пробовали установить кодировку консоли через `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` или `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");`?

Comment: @goldstar_labs пробовал setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); Сейчас попробовал Ваш вариант setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8"); и он сработал. SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); Этот вариант сразу ошибку выдает. Я думал что нужно задавать кодировку через коннектор. а тут получается обычная setlocale работает...Спасибо большое

Comment: как я понимаю, суть в следующем: база и конектор у вас в кодировке утф-8, но сама консоль (куда вы выводите) - нет, поэтому необходимо и для консоли установить утф-8. Если вы, например, будете писать вывод в файл, то туда запишется валидный текст в утф-8 и кодировку консоли можно не менять.

Comment: @goldstar_labs Благодарю за разъяснения.